# (Django jwt) ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python, django, postman, backend

I have created a `UserViewSet`in my Django project to get user data via a get request, the viewset should be expecting a bearer type access token in the body. However, when I make the request through postman, it return a error: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

My `UserViewSet` looks like this:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer 
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    
    def get_object(self):
        lookup_field_value = self.kwargs[self.lookup_field]

        obj = Account.objects.get(lookup_field_value)
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)

        return obj
```

Now I know it is also expecting me to include a `lookup field` in the request, but I have not idea how and where to put it. My  `lookup field` should be the `id` by default, so I just make the request by this endpoint: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/auth/user/2/` in order to get user data of user `id=2`.

Anybody has an idea why I am getting this error, and how to solve it?